# WCF IEnumerable - Streamed Transport Net Tcp

Tags: wcf, stream, nettcpbinding, large-data

I need to streaming a large content with WCF and deferred execution (using NetTcpBinding), in other words, return a list of person (can be anything) from a database through a WCF service without consume all memory in the server side.

I have tried the solution in this post: [Streaming large content with WCF and deferred execution](http://weblogs.asp.net/cibrax/archive/2008/06/10/streaming-large-content-with-wcf-and-deferred-execution.aspx)

Using BasicHttpBinding it works like a charm, but when using NetTcpBinding....well...not working.

Can anyone help me with this??

Tks!

Project here: [WCF Streaming IEnumerable](https://github.com/marcoaoteixeira/Wcf_IEnumerable_Stream)

Comment: Uhm...yes...need better explanation...
The current project (on Git) is using NetTcp to transfer a Message (System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message) object to the client and, the client, read it like a stream, the message is an enumerable. To create the message, i'm using the static method Message.CreateMessage, and, pass a custom bodywriter that serializes a IEnumerable of T to a XML. When, in the client, i try to read the message, the message body only contains a node "Fault". That does not occurs when using Basic Http binding. But, i need NetTcp Binding... =/

Comment: It's like query a database for a list of items, but instead of buffering everything and transport to the client, stream the data...

Answer (score 0):

Here is guidance on transferring large data with streaming.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733742.aspx

At the bottom of the page is a link to some samples, one of which shows using TCP.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms789010.aspx

If this doesn't help, then perhaps you could provide more detail on how it is failing (error message)?